# Minecraft Forge Wearable Item

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

im creating a mod with custom item and I want to make that item wearable and I don't know how. This is my code of the Mod item.

```
public static final RegistryObject<Item> SNOWMAN_KING = ITEMS.register("Snowman King",
        () -> new Item(new Item.Properties().isImmuneToFire().maxStackSize(1).group(ModItemGroup.COSMETICS)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register an ArmorItem. If you wish to add extra functionality, you will need to create a class extending ArmorItem, override the methods you need and register that instead.

Your code should look something like this:

```java
public static final RegistryObject<Item> SNOWMAN_KING = ITEMS.register("snowman_king",
        () -> new ArmorItem(ArmorMaterials.DIAMOND, EquipmentSlot.HEAD, 
        new Item.Properties().isImmuneToFire().maxStackSize(1).group(ModItemGroup.COSMETICS)));
```

Also, when you're registering an item, the name of the item should be all lowercase and shouldn't include any spaces or special characters.